# How to use string slicing to print a string left to right

Tags: python

I have a task uses string slicing. To do this I need to start and the end and go up. up to zero. So if it’s efg It starts at __g goes to _fg and then efg. I’m confused how to do this with string slicing in a while loop.I know to get the last character I would use -1. What I have right now does kind of what I want just not with the last letter and instead the first letter. I know it has to do with my slicing but I can’t figure it out

```
N=len(s)
I=0
while I< N:
    Print((n-I)*” “ + s[0:i:1]
```

Comment: You will have to create a new string with the underscores e.g. `s = (len(string) - 1) * '_' + string[-1]`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blanks"? Does the space character (i.e. `chr(32)`) work?

Answer (score 0):

The negative index should be the *starting* character:

```
> "efg"[-1:]
"g"
> "efg"[-2:]
"fg"
> "efg"[-3:]
"efg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what output you were expecting, but this is the code I came up with from what I interpreted:

```
s = "efg"
n = len(s)
i = 0
while(i < n):
  print("_" * (n-i-1) + s[((i+1) * -1):])
  i+=1
```

Output:

```
__g
_fg
efg
```

We can print out one less than the difference of `i` and `n` number of `_`'s, and then slice as @chepner mentioned.

The key part of this problem is finding a way to use `i` and `n` to get the correct number of repetitions of `_` and the correct slicing of `s`.

Since `i` will start at 0 and end at 2, and `n` = 3, and in this example the number of `_`s goes from 2 to 1 to 0, a simple equation would be: number of `_`s = `n` - `i` - 1.

Similarly, to slice from -1, -2, and then -3 onwards, this relationship is just equal to `-(i+1)`.

I hope this helped! Let me know if you need any further help or clarification.